# 404 Error on Inbox Web Part

Tags: 2010

Im trying to use the inbox web part on a "my site" page.  Im adding the web part and adding my web exchange URL, but the part is resulting in a 404 error.. any ideas?

It looks like its resolving to the following url: https://exchange.mydomain.com/ericw@mydomain.com/?cmd=loadmodule&part=1&module=inbox&view=Two%20Line

Thanks In Advance

Update: Still not sure what to do here.  Anyone know if this is down the correct path? - http://markhaverty.com/sharepoint/configuring-the-my-calendar-and-my-inbox-web-parts/ Do I need to configure exchange OWA at all in a particular manner to make these things talk? I should add, were running exchange 2007.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the link to the Office Outlook Web Access server and not directly to Microsoft Exchange Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i believe you would have to configure the Outlook Web Access in the environment.   I have not tried it my self - but here are steps to configure Office OutLook web access server for exchange 2007.

http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/3611-how-to-configure-outlook-web-access-for-exchange-2007/

Once you have installed it, i think you would have to use the link of the Office Outlook Web Access server in the inbox webpart.Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks sp, so just to be clear, these web part will NOT work with Exchange 2010?  If not, is there any potential workaround's available?  Just concerned, because we will be upgrading Exchange at some point..

Comment: This is the updated ariticle on the discontinued features 
Web Parts. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998911.aspx#Disc2007to2010, Look at the outlook web app featured section.It mentions that the feature has been brought back in SP1 for exchange 2010.

Comment: Once you install the SP1 of exchange 2010, then you can use the OWA webparts as usual - i have updated the text.